# how to show a file opened by xcode in finder

Tags: xcode

How do I find the location of a file opened by xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click (or Control + left-click) anywhere in the document that you want to find (or on its entry in the project navigator pane on the left), and select the "Show in Finder" option.  Works in XCode4, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 15+ right click on anywhere on the opened source code file -> navigate -> show in finder